# apt-get update/upgrade not finding latest version of Percona server

Tags: apt, upgrade

I've got Percona DB 5.6 on several 12.04 servers.  On a few of them, I've been able to successfully upgrade to the latest version (5.6.17) using

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

On several others, apt-get update + upgrade tells me there's nothing to do.  Why isn't it finding the most recent version?

Up-to-date version from servers that did update: "Server version: 5.6.17-65.0-587.precise-log (Ubuntu)"

Version from servers that are not updating: "Server version: 5.6.15-63.0-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 63.0"

I have confirmed that the following lines are in /etc/apt/sources.list on all servers:

```
deb http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main
```

(and it had to work at some point, because they were all installed originally using apt-get)